# Use of Hamlet's $case with records and ADTs

Tags: haskell, yesod, hamlet

It would seem that Hamlet's `$case` expression should be remarkably useful, but I can't figure out how one would match against an record type with multiple constructors short of pattern matching (with a unique name) each of the fields. Say I have a data type,

```
 data A = A1 { v1,v2,v3 :: Int }
        | A2 { g :: Double}
```

In my template, I would want to render `A1` values differently from `A2` values. One would think I could simply do,

```
 $case myA
    $of a@(A1 {})
      <p>This is an A1: #{show $ v1 a}
    $of a@(A2 {})
      <p>This is an A2: #{show $ g a}
```

Unfortunately, this snippet fails to compile with a syntax error, suggesting that the `@` syntax isn't supported. If I remove the `a@`, I get another syntax error, this time suggesting that the record brace notation also isn't supported.

Finally, in desperation, once can try,

```
 $case myA
    $of A1 _ _ _
      ...
```

But alas, even this doesn't compile (conflicting definitions of _). Consequently, it seems that the only option is,

```
 $case myA
    $of A1 v1 v2 v3
      ...
```

This sort of order-based pattern matching gets extremely tiresome with large datatypes, especially when one is forced to name every field.

So, what am I missing here? Is case analysis in Hamlet really as limited as it seems? What is the recommended way to match against the constructors of a ADT (and later refer to fields)? Is the fact that I even want to do this sort of matching a sign that I'm Doing It Wrong(TM)?

Comment: Case matching is almost always the best approach, so you are not doing it wrong.  This is the peril of working in a DSL and it is why many advocate that Haskell itself should always be your DSL.

Comment: I wasn't terribly clear about this, but I meant to imply that perhaps I shouldn't be doing the case analysis in the template. I thought that Hamlet's lack of a rich case analysis primitive was a sign that I shouldn't placing so much logic in the template

Answer (score 2):

You can track hamlet processing.

The answer is in the non-exposed module Text.Hamlet.Parse where

```
controlOf = do
    _   <- try $ string "$of"
    pat <- many1 $ try $ spaces >> ident
    _   <- spaceTabs
    eol
    return $ LineOf pat

where
  ident = Ident <$> many1 (alphaNum <|> char '_' <|> char '\'')
```

so only a sequence of one or more (spaces followed by (identifier or wildcard)) is accepted.

You may extend it from here.

Cheers!

Comment: So I take it that this is just a deficiency in the current implementation of `$case`? I could try adding support for the `@` syntax, although I'm afraid the full record syntax is a bit more than I would like to chew.